# Probability of getting off at the bus stop

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> 6 stops on the line, and a car with 4 passengers. Assume they are equally likely to get off at any stop. What is the probability that **A** $2$ passengers get off stop 2, and $2$ get off stop 4? **B** $2$ get off stop 1, and $2$ get of at another stop (but they get off at the same stop as each other?)

**A**
I get $1/81$ which is wrong?

**B** I get $5/6^4$ which is also wrong?

Why are both of these wrong?

Comment: I don't think anyone can say **why** these answers are wrong unless you explain why you thought they are right.  If you just want the correct answers, that's a different question.

Comment: If they are equally likely to get off at any stop, then shouldn't the answer for  **A** and **B** be the same?

Comment: @ Shraddheya Shendre -- By addition of mutiually exclusive events, the answer for (B) should be 5 times the answer for (A).

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both the parts, the total number of possible ways by which the passengers can exit is $6^4$.

For part **A**,
the ways by which $2$ passengers can be grouped is $\binom{4}{2}$ (and the other $2$ are automatically grouped so there's nothing else to do). So the number of ways in which the exiting of passengers can be done is $\binom{4}{2}$.
So the required probability in part **A** is $$\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{6^4}$$

For part **B**,
the number of ways of grouping remains same:  $\binom{4}{2}$; but now the exit stop can be assigned in $5$ ways (one group exits at stop $1$ and other can exit on remaining $5$ stops). So the required probability is $$\frac{5 \times \binom{4}{2}}{6^4}$$

Comment: Since, as you say, the other $2$ passengers are automatically grouped, this means that you're double counting.

Comment: So you are saying that I shouldn't count for the switching of the groups (and hence not multiply by $2$)?

Comment: Right -- don't multiply by 2. The ordered 4-tuple is completely determined once you select the two passengers who get off at stop 2.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the answer. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: No problem -- it looks fine now.